# "Failure Sending mail" error despite to the fact that i allowed the less secure option

Tags: c#

I am sending mail from c# but it produces "Failure Sending mail". I have enabled less secured option but still produces error. I have checked the help on internet but not working. Please give proper solution.
Below is my code:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smptServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("mama.bannu123@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add(Convert.ToString(this.txtToMailAddress.Text));
        mail.Subject=Convert.ToString(this.txtSubjectMail.Text);
        mail.Body=Convert.ToString(this.txtBodyMail.Text);

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachFile = new Attachment("D:\\exp1.pdf");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
        smptServer.Port = 587;
        smptServer.Credentials = new 
           System.Net.NetworkCredential("mama.bannu123@gmail.com", "password code");
        smptServer.EnableSsl = true;
        smptServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("Message Send Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have checked the help on internet but not working` so what did you try, what have you looked at. What questions have you followed, what results did you get?

Comment: I tried the less secure option and checked "ON". I also changed the port to 25.  I got the error "Failure Sending Mail" and still the problem exist.

Comment: GMAIL only accepts secure connections with port 587.  Often on corporate networks port 587 will be blocked at the firewall.  Also with gmail if the send box in the account is full an error will occur.

Comment: For SMTP related errors, it is mandatory to _always_ check the `InnerException` of your `ex` exception. E.g. `MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);`.

Comment: still gives the mentioned error with the use of ex.InnerException.Message. Please suggest any remedy i am really worried about this.

Comment: I tried again now this error shows : "unable to read data from the transport connection an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". Please recommend proper solution of the error